# Implementing Two Step Verfication for ASP.Net MVC 4 Website having EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

We have a ASP.Net MVC 4 website which uses WebSecurity(Membership provider) to authenticate the user.
Entity Framework Code First is used in this application.

I have to implement Two Step Verification feature by asking a security Q which the user has answered it during the registration process.

So if the user tries to access the website from a any computer, he will be asked the security Q. There are two check boxes, where User can either select 'Remember me' or 'Don't Remember me'. Once that Security answer is validated, then we should store that answer in a cookie on client side.
Next time when the user is accessing that site from the same computer, he will not be asked to enter the security Q. If he access it from different computer, he should be prompted for the security Q.

In order to to implement this-

1) Should i use ASP.Net Identity and OWIN to the current design?

2) Do i need to convert the authentication to Forms authentication?

Any help/ideas on this would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

WH

Comment: Asking a security question is not an example of two-factor authentication as the information is still the same class as a password (i.e. "something you know" or a "shared secret"). The second-factor should be "something you have" such as an RNG security token (e.g. RSA SecureID), a smartcard, or SMS text message.

Comment: Web Security? What is that?

Comment: Thanks @Dai for the quick response.
Ideally the requirement is to implement the two step verification process..We are not suing any external tokens..

Comment: @Deilan- System.Web.Security which uses Membership class to validate user credentials

Comment: @Deilan: [WebSecurity class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) (precursor to Identity IIRC)